# SBS2011 out of disk space

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

Scenario:

SO: SBS2011  - HD: 186GB - Available space: 0

- The Exchange and Sharepoint databases are stored on a different drive,
- Users data are saved on a different drive

DIRs and file greater than 1GB:

- /windows/winsxs -> 45,5GB
- /windows/installer -> 5,5GB
- /windows/assembly -> 2,5GB
- /unknown -> 113,9 GB  (this file is shown by windir only)

I tried:

1) Disk cleaner, the tool claim to be able cleaning 18Gb of system file, but once started and run for some minutes it stops with no message.

2) dism /online /cleanup-image /spsuperseded with no success

I already cleaned all temporary dirs and deleted all unused accounts getting 200MB of free space for a few minutes.

Any tip? thx

Comment: Looks like the problem is the sharepoint log file it is more than 100Gb, I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 1):

I clean the following location with a batch file and it cleans out more than any other Windows-included tool:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin\
C:\Recycler\
C:\Recycled\
C:\System Volume Information\
%TEMP%\
C:\MSOCache\ 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Results\
C:\Program Files\Google\Update\Download\
%SystemRoot%\Prefetch\
%SystemRoot%\pchealth\ERRORREP\
%SystemRoot%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\
%SystemRoot%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\Logs\
%SystemRoot%\System32\spool\Printers\
%SystemRoot%\Temp\
%SystemRoot%\Logs\
%SystemRoot%\Debug\
%SystemRoot%\MiniDump\
%SystemRoot%\Security\Logs\
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem\Logs\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\SystemCache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\javaws\cache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Messenger\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Contacts\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\SystemCache\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\javaws\cache\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Opera\Opera\cache\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Media Player\Art Cache\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\
%USERPROFILE%\Recent\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp\History\
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp\Temporary Internet Files\
```

There are several locations that I mentioned here and Windows does not clean with it's tools.